# convert decimal to hex python

Tags: python, networking, decimal, hex

Im building a server in python, i need to convert a decimal value to hex like this :

let's say the packet start by 4 bytes which define the packet lenght :
00 00 00 00
if the len(packet) = 255 we would send :
00 00 00 ff

Now my problem is that sometimes the packet is bigger than 256 as for example 336, then it would be :
00 00 01 50

i dont know how to do that in python, and i will really appreciate any help.
Thanks !

Comment: have you looked at http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">i", 336)
'\x00\x00\x01P'
```

The [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct) packs and unpacks python values into bytes.  The `">i"` format means big-endian 4-byte integer.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
"%0.8x" % data
```

Sample:

```
>>> print "%0.8x" % 366
0000016e

>>> print "%0.8x" % 336
00000150
```

Comment: I don't know why this one-liner isn't more popular. Maybe it's newer Python syntax, regardless, it works for me in Python 2.7.8. Thanks!