# Convert integer to hex with padding in Python

Tags: python, hex, decimal, base-conversion

I have an integer `(67)` that needs to be converted to hex and stored as a string like:

`"\x00\x00\x00\x43"`

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Dang, my copy/paste buffer missed. I meant to mark this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708598/convert-decimal-to-hex-python?rq=1

Comment: I tried hex(integer)[2:].zfill(8). But this only returns a hex without the "\x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated due to ambiguity in OP.

Try...

```
def convert(i):
    result = ''
    for c in struct.pack('>i', 67):
        c = hex(ord(c))[2:]
        if len(c) < 2:
            c = '0%s' % c
        result += '\\x%s' % c
    return result

>>> print convert(67)
\x00\x00\x00\x43
```

Comment: LOL I should start copying answers instead of marking as duplicates from now on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708598/convert-decimal-to-hex-python?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. Sure, it shouldn't be _upvoted_, because it was posted after the "possible duplicate" link to the exact same answer, and the question should be closed anyway… but it's not wrong, misleading, confusing, etc., so why downvote it?

Comment: struct.pack('>i", 67) returns "C". I need it to return "\x00\x00\x00\x43"

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice you'd marked this as a dupe before I posted the answer. If you're going to mark as a dupe, should you not also close the question at the same time to avoid confusion?

Comment: @abarnert I downvoted because it was wrong and doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Aya Marking as duplicate is a recent wording change to closing as duplicate. They are equivalent.

Comment: @user2267580 struct.pack('>i", 67) returns '\x00\x00\x00C' which is the same as "\x00\x00\x00\x43", unless you actually wanted a string containing the backslashes?

Comment: Yes, I want the actual string "\x00\x00\x00\x43" returned.

Comment: Updated. There's probably a better method, but I only answered this because I originally thought it was a one-liner. Had I known I would be chastised for my troubles, I probably wouldn't have bothered. :/

Comment: Downvote is now an upvote :)